# How to fix receipt/confirmation attached PDF alignment in email?

Tags: civimail, pdf

Civicrm email receipt/confirmation attach PDF files alignment issue.

We facing alignment issue in attached PDF file, Left side margin high and it is creating empty pages.

Which file needs to edit for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe set up the default PDF form (Administer Communications PDF Format, ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FpdfFormats&reset=1) which allows you to define margins